# Vue.js pass a function that returns either true or false as a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass a function that returns true or false as a prop, a function similar to this

```
canBeUsed(): boolean {
      if (this.usable) {
        return true
      } 
     return false
     }
```

The component that I am passing the props to has the following code

```
props: {
canBeUsed: {
type: Boolean
}
}
```

But I get the warning  `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "canBeUsed". Expected Boolean, got Function`

The error is because I am passing a function that returns true or false, however the code works as it should. It is still getting the boolean value, I just need to fix this warning, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I suggest to use **computed** vue2 :https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
or vue3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#standalone-computed-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the prop type to a Function:

```
props: {
  canBeUsed: {
    type: Function
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont know why I didnt think of this lol, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are doing:

```html
<component :can-be-used="canBeUsed"></component>
```

This, indeed passes the function as a prop. However, your prop qualify for a boolean one, and you should pass the result of that function instead:

```html
<component :can-be-used="canBeUsed()"></component>
```

This approach can cause some performance issues if the function is complex (it will get called on every template rerendering). In this case, the best approach is to use a computed prop.

```html
<component :can-be-used="canBeUsed"></component>
```

```js
computed: {
  canBeUsed(){
     if (this.usable) {
        return true
     } 
     return false
  }
}
```

This will reevaluate prop value only when needed.

Comment: hey, im currently using the second one, and is currently inside a v-for. what if i need to pass in a parameter inside that function that i am currently using? eg. `v-for="item in items" ...  :can-be-used="canBeUsed(item)"`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass `this.usable` to the component props?

`<component :can-be-used="usable"></component>`

If all your component cares about is whether or not usable is true or false, that should be it. The data processing can happen on the parent to determine `this.usable`'s value.

Comment: there is more code in the method that I didn't include, that does more logic checks on that data variable

Comment: This is what I also would recommend. It is better to identify that the prop is a Boolean than `props: { canBeUsed: {  type: Function  } }`.

Comment: I don't see why you would pass a function as a prop. Do the necessary data operations on each component where necessary.